# Using JavaScript to access a JSON array from PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to understand how my PHP script can pass an array to my JavaScript code. Using the following PHP, I pass an array:

```
$c = array(3,2,7);

echo json_encode($c);
```

My JavaScript is as follows:

```
    $.post("getLatLong.php", { latitude: 500000},
        function(data) {
            arrayData = data
            document.write(arrayData)
            document.write(arrayData[0]);
            document.write(arrayData[0]);
            document.write(arrayData[0]);
        });
</script>
```

What is printed out on the screen is

```
[3,2,7][3,
```

I'm trying to understand how json_encode works - I thought I would be able to pass the array to a variable, and then access it like a normal JavaScript array, but it views my array as one large text string. How do ensure that it reads it like an array?

Comment: Your example is a 2-dimensional array. Try using `data[0][0]`, `[0][1]`,`[0][2]`, etc. to access `3`,`2`,`7` respectively.

Comment: hmm, I understand now that it is a 2D array. but even if I change it, it still reads it as a string.

Comment: @Brad Christie: It is not at all a 2-dimensional array. What makes you think that?

Comment: @Felix: Look a their revision history. Their first code implemented (what's being referred to as `$c`) as `array(array(3,2,7))`. But, I take full accountability for missing that they didn't specify they wanted JSON parsed (though I can't confirm if they included a `header()` in the AJAX page specifying JSON that `.post` wouldn't take care of it automatically)

Comment: @Brad Christie: Oh I see. Nevermind then :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the `dataType` argument to [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
$.post("getLatLong.php", { latitude: 500000},
   function(data){         
   // ...
}, 'json');
```

Then `data` will be properly decoded.

Alternatively you can also use [`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) in the callback.

**Explanation of JSON:**

[JSON](http://json.org) is a data exchange format. It specifies the structure of the **data string** that is transmitted. `json_encode` takes a PHP data structure like an array or an object and transformes it to JSON, i.e. a string with a certain format.

`json_encode($c)` will give you the string `"[3,2,7]"`.

On the client site, you receive that string, but you have to **decode** it in to proper JavaScript data structures. So `$.parseJSON(data)` will give you a JavaScript array with 3 elements (or if you pass 'json' as third parameter to `.post()`, jQuery is doing the decoding automatically for you).

Comment: As it turns out, if they placed `header('Content-Type: application/json')` it appears `.post` would have worked correctly (or at least not needed to be explicitly noted it's a JSON reply [which makes sense])

Comment: @Brad where would I place the header? Just trying to understand this overall process... as the code is now working.

Comment: place the header in `getLatLong.php`

Comment: @celenius: ... before any output.